# unexpected output when pattern matching exception on a promise

Tags: exception, promise, reason, bucklescript

I have the following [piece of code](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try.html?reason=ATA2FMBdk8GdoF4BQIQCk4DoAKAnAewFsBLOcLPeA0AN3AAoAiACXFFAKYEpgAfAHzBMuQqXJZIAC3AA7APoN5BAEYArYIiF4AhmUYA5ApHkAzAgFdZAE27cA3KjBRgAa3B5NTkHADuJSABjKRh4aABvb35gcAAPQPAAB0gSAllgIxNzK2tNIRFOAHNmWWNgbJseKL5geTzhbCLmCusqtGAAX3sgA):

```
  let test =
    Js.Promise.resolve("Hello") |> Js.Promise.then_(_obj => raise(Not_found));
  let ker =
    switch test {
    | exception Not_found => Js.log("not found")
    | _ => Js.log("found")
    };
```

The output it produces is:

```
"found"
```

Why does the above code not produce the output `"not found"` and what should I do to make sure the first branch in the switch statement gets executed ?

Answer (score 3):

This mostly has to do with the way JavaScript handles exceptions that get thrown inside promises. They need to be handled using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch , which is bound to https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Js.Promise.html#VALcatch , because they are 'caught' inside the promise and stay inside the promise context.

Concretely, I would turn your example into this:

```jsx
let test = Js.Promise.(resolve("Hello") |> then_(_obj => raise(Not_found)));

let ker = Js.Promise.(test
  |> then_((_) => "found" |> Js.log |> resolve)
  |> catch((_) => "Not found" |> Js.log |> resolve));
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case I'm working on my own exception like `exception LoginApiFailed(string);` and I want to read the `string` contents. You seem to ignoring the exception value, can I actually read the exception content in it ?

Comment: There are some good examples - including this exact case of a custom exception with parameterizable text - in the cookbook by glennsl here https://github.com/glennsl/bucklescript-cookbook#error-handling (with the reason-tools browser extension, it should convert it directly into ReasonML for you)

Comment: Unfortunately they seem to be in Ocaml and it is out of my reach currently. Can you possibly give an example for it ?

Comment: @Sibi As he said, use [reason-tools](https://github.com/reasonml/reason-tools) to convert OCaml to Reason

Comment: @Sibi yeah, the person who designed this binding made a deliberate choice to discourage throwing exceptions in promises. He recommends using the `Js.Result.t` type instead, which is basically like Haskell's `Either`, to encode success and failure. So, `...then_(_obj => Js.Result.Error(Not_found))` (here we're just putting the exception in a value instead of throwing it). Then later, `Js.Promise.(test |> then_(fun Js.Result.Ok(_) => "found" |> Js.log |> resolve | Js.Result.Error(Not_found) => "Not found" |> Js.log |> resolve))`

Comment: @Sibi here's a more complete example of what I recommend https://reasonml.github.io/en/try.html?reason=DYUwLgBGIM6QvBAUjAdABQE4HsC2BLGEVACk1m2ADcQSVUAlWAV2DFQHkBrEgIgAkQwYNl4BKMRAA+APigALEADsA+iRIrJ8GQCgIEcjEo06aJjFbsAophyYSAOWxgVAM2zMlAEwkSA3Do6oJAiAObmxrQAHloQUdJy9GEJyGhYeITEhpEBOtBwKfTpBESoYIqqJK6eOlKpjCxsnDyaENoQYRHUtLzunl7itfXmlqg2do7Obh7eWnKdFN18TpB93oN1Km3z2OGLJrwAqkpcStgA7koQILbYmOJiAUA

Answer (score 2):

Because a promise is a promise, regardless if it's a failed one or not.
In your case, at some point it will be resolved to a failed promise, but it will never raise/throw an error. It will just be a promise whose inner value, at some point will be an error (a non thrown error).

In order to catch the error (or value), you need to use the `catch` function on your `test` binding. The `catch` function does with rejected promises, what the `then` function does to fulfilled ones.

Snippet:

```
let handleData = [@bs.open] (
  fun
  | Invalid_argument(_) => Js.Promise.resolve(0)
  | Not_found => Js.Promise.resolve(1)
  | Sys_error(_) => Js.Promise.resolve(2)
  );  

let ker =
    test |> Js.Promise.catch(handleData)
```

Comment: Is there a way to inspect the Exception inside the `catch` function ? Basically let's say that the exception has some useful string which I want to print upon, is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, do a switch (with destructuring) on the value passed to the function passed to the `catch` function.